# List only path, file name and size in Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd

In Windows command prompt, I'm trying to list only path, file name and size, of all files including in a folder and its sub folders.
Like:

```
dir /s /b /a-d "C:\MainFolder\"
```

Problem is that I don't know how to show size of file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5):

From the command line:

```
for %F in ("c:\MainFolder\*") do @echo %~zF  %F
```

Double up the percents if you use the command in a batch file.

Type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command prompt for more information on the various values that are available with FOR variable expansion.

Comment: Good answer. An addition would be to simply change to the desired Folder and then to type `(for %F in ("*") do @echo %F %~zF) & (dir|grep "File")` in order to also get the Total File Count and the Total Size Count. Get the `grep` App from the [CygWin](http://cygwin.com/) App.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command ---

```
for %%a in (*) do echo %%a
```